# disable everty javascript event out side of fancyfox popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, fancybox

I am opening a fancybox for session time out of a logged in user after some waiting period the popup is disabling and the user is logged out automatically, but if I clicking outside of the popup the counter time sets 0 so it is not logged out.

```
window.idleTime = 0;
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    //Increment the idle time counter every minute.
    var idleInterval = setInterval(timerIncrement, 60000); 
    //Zero the idle timer on mouse movement.
    jQuery(this).mousemove(function (e) { 
        idleTime = 0;
        //alert(idleTime);
    });
    jQuery(this).keypress(function (e) {
        idleTime = 0;
        //alert(idleTime);
    });

    jQuery(".classname").live("click", function(){
        //alert('');
        idleTime = 0;
    })  

});
function timerIncrement() {
    var timedouturl = "logout.php?sTimeOut=1";
    //alert('Calling..');
    idleTime = idleTime + 1;
    if (idleTime > 2) { // 1 minutes
        //alert('Time Out =>'+idleTime);
        //window.location.reload();
        jQuery.fancybox({
        'type'      : 'ajax',
        'href'      : 'popup.php',
        'autoSize'  : false,
        'width'     : 450,
        'height'    : 'auto',
        afterLoad   : function(){
            //alert("IdleTime :"+idleTime);
           setTimeout( function() {
                                    jQuery.fancybox.close();
                                    //alert("LastIdleTime :"+ window.idleTime);
                                    if (window.idleTime > 2){
                                        window.location.href = timedouturl;
                                    }
                                    },60000); 

          }
        });
    }
}
```

I want to prevent every js event when popup opened outside of the popup. any idea ?

here

```
jQuery(".classname").live("click", function(){
        //alert('');
        idleTime = 0;
    })
```

is for when clicking ok button on the fancybox.

Comment: if fancybox is open and the visitors moves the mouse, do you want to reset `idleTime` to `0`? so no logout? ...unless they wait 1 minutes with fancybox open?

Comment: BTW `live()` is deprecated, use `on()` instead (requires jQuery v1.7+)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a boolean that keeps track of when your popup is open, then only reset timeout when popup isn't open:

```
window.idleTime = 0;
var timeoutPopupOpen = false;
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    //Increment the idle time counter every minute.
    var idleInterval = setInterval(timerIncrement, 60000); 
    //Zero the idle timer on mouse movement.
    jQuery(this).mousemove(function (e) {
        if (!timeoutPopupOpen) {
            idleTime = 0;
        }
        //alert(idleTime);
    });
    jQuery(this).keypress(function (e) {
        if (!timeoutPopupOpen) {
            idleTime = 0;
        }
        //alert(idleTime);
    });

    jQuery(".classname").live("click", function(){
        if (!timeoutPopupOpen) {
            idleTime = 0;
        }
        //alert('');
    })  

});
function timerIncrement() {
    var timedouturl = "logout.php?sTimeOut=1";
    //alert('Calling..');
    idleTime = idleTime + 1;
    if (idleTime > 2) { // 1 minutes
        //alert('Time Out =>'+idleTime);
        //window.location.reload();
        timeoutPopupOpen = true
        jQuery.fancybox({
            'type'      : 'ajax',
            'href'      : 'popup.php',
            'autoSize'  : false,
            'width'     : 450,
            'height'    : 'auto',
            afterClose  : function(){
                timeoutPopupOpen = false;
            },
            afterLoad   : function(){
                //alert("IdleTime :"+idleTime);
               setTimeout( function() {
                                    jQuery.fancybox.close();
                                    //alert("LastIdleTime :"+ window.idleTime);
                                    if (window.idleTime > 2){
                                        window.location.href = timedouturl;
                                    }
                                    },60000); 

            }
        });
    }
}
```

I'm not sure which Fancybox you are using because I can't seem to find the `afterLoad` option in the [fb2docs](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) or [these docs from fancybox.net](http://fancybox.net/home), but besically just keep track of when someone starts and closes fancybox so you know if you should be cancelling the timeout.

Comment: `afterLoad` is a callback so you find it under the "callbacks" tab http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs (fancybox v2.x)